# Azure Pay-as-you-go typical pricing

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I am required to learn Azure Databricks as well as other Azure services that require something more than just the Free Trial. I don’t really have any problem doing this.

However, my question is how much can I expect to be charged monthly, weekly, etc. when strictly performing learning-related tasks?

I just want to become familiar with the services and just Azure in general, but I want to know what other people’s experiences have been. I don’t want to set up clusters on a Databricks project just to learn and figure it out and end up costing myself 50 bucks for something I’m really just testing.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I believe your question is basically a commercial inquiry. It should probably be sent to the commercial team of azure. Also, the actual answer is subject to change over time, rendering any answer in this website not so useful in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get very far without actually paying anything, especially with the free trial. However, you can also accrue extremely high costs very quickly in pay-as-you-go. There are too many Azure Services to get any more specific within the scope of this site.

Three tips to get you started:

- Use the [Azure Pricing calculator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/) for the services you want to learn to get a feeling for the costs and how they develop.
- Set a budget on your subscription to avoid accidentally spending too much.
- Delete your services as soon as you are done with them, even if you need to recreate them the next day. You often pay by the hour.

Comment: Thank you so much, actually! That definitely clarified things for me. I have a much better idea of what I’m going for now. I’m just barely getting into Azure and Cloud Computing in general but that set me on the right path.

Comment: Glad I could help! If you feel my answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.